# Jmeter Throughput Shaping Timer not achieving desired rps

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

I am using the throughput shaping timer in combination with the concurrency thread group

In the concurrency thread group I have set [${__tstFeedback(test,1,100,10)}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcgR6.png)   in order for my test to dynamically control the thread groups.
*test is the name of my throughput shaping timer.

I want to target 6rps  but when running the test and checking the throughput on the summary report the throughput is 43/min.
The response time of my endpoint is anywhere from 68ms to 500ms.

Anyone have any luck in getting the shaping timer to work?  Or have any other suggestions to offer?

[jmeter config for concurrency thread group and shaping timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pisgV.png)

Comment: Can you show your element configuration ?Thanks

Comment: Not sure I am following but have added the pics of the configuration from the jmeter UI

Comment: I have had issues using the Concurrency thread group, it hangs for me after a while and doesn't apply desired load. I would start by using the regular Thread group and setting to 3 threads since you need 6 rps and your max response time seems to be .5s